# Show files with nuxeo and cmis request

Tags: drupal, cmis, nuxeo

I have an issue with a CMIS request to a nuxeo server. When I make a request like

```
/nuxeo/atom/cmis/default/children?id=123456789
```

, the nuxeo server send only the folder include in the folder with id=123456789.

I would like to see the files too. Does the request is correct?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using a CMIS client, such as [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org/)

Comment: yes it's a drupal module so i use this api [cmisapi](https://www.drupal.org/project/cmis) but in the browser of this api i do not see the files i see only the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.

Here's an example response I get when listing the content of a folder "ppp", which has one child "18-content_view_slideshow.png"

`curl 'https://myuser:mypassword@testserver/nuxeo/atom/cmis/default/children?id=63f1d9d6-4a0e-4018-8100-f66c132b1add'`

See the XML response at http://pastebin.com/h5WSWend

Are you sure you have proper authorization to see the files? Also, you didn't specify the version of the Nuxeo server you're using.

Comment: Nuxeo CAP version: 6.0. i do exactly the same request but i don't see my files, when i do a request like 
`http://Administrator:Administrator@server/nuxeo/site/api/v1/path/my_path/@children` 
          i see the files

Comment: new! 
i test and it's only in a folder in the others i show the files with a cmis request

Comment: Then it may be a folder not exposed to the CMIS endpoint, because it's not under the workspaces for instance. Or the documents are proxies.

Comment: i'm not very good with nuxeo, if i publish a document in a folder this document is consider a document proxy ?

Comment: So ok i can't see the document proxy via CMIS thank's !

Comment: Yes this is described in [CMIS Model Mapping](http://doc.nuxeo.com/display/NXDOC/CMIS#CMIS-ModelMappingmapping): _Proxy documents are not visible in CMIS_.